# Вопрос по организации поиска

Tags: php

Добрый день, появилась проблема по организации поиска на сайте. Имеется сайт (онлайн магазин), который не имеет собственной базы продуктов. Вся база продуктов берется из Amazon (Amazon API) и eBay (eBay API) и поиск по данным API организован на Английском языке, но мне требуется получать результаты поиска при запросе как на Английском языке (пример Cloting), Русском (пример Одежда), Русский англ. (пример: Odejda). 
Для решения проблемы Русского языка я подключил Google Translate API, который первым делом делает Detect языка и при обнаружении что язык английский - переводит ее и делает запрос.

С английским языком проблем нет - если Google Detect выводит язык EN то просто происходит поиск, без переводов.

А с "Русский англ. (пример: Odejda)." не знаю как решить проблему.

Comment: То, что вы называете русский англ., на самом деле называется транслит (translit, transliteration). Во всяком случае раньше так было.

Comment: А откуда изначально берутся слова в транслите? Или вам надо результат перевода на русский ещё и перевести в транслит?

Comment: обрати транслит в русские буквы при условии что такого слова нет на английском

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Рабочий вариант - используйте готовую или сделайте свою "азбуку" транслита. Например:

```
    $ABC = array(
        'а' => 'a',
        'б' => 'b',
        'в' => 'v',
        ...
        'э' => 'e',
        'ю' => 'u',
        'я' => 'ya'
    );
```

И просто производите замену симоволов :)